# avg() value to a default value 0 for non existent records in foreign table

Tags: mysql, sql

### Tables

- SubscriptionMaster (subId,subLink)
- AlertMaster (alertId,alertTitle,alertText,subId)
- AlertDetails (alertId,userId,voteVal,userNote)

  - *alertId is (F.K.) to AlertMaster*

### Query:

```
  SELECT alrt.alertid,
         alrt.alertTitle, 
         alrt.alertDetails, 
         alrt.alertDate, 
         alrt.alertURL,
         sub.subTitle,
         avg(dtl.avgVote) 
    FROM alertDetails dtl,
         ALERTMASTER alrt,
         SUBSCRIPTIONMASTER sub
   WHERE alrt.subId = 1 
     AND alrt.subId = sub.subId 
GROUP BY alertId 
ORDER BY alertDate DESC 
   limit 0,10;
```

There are many records in alertMaster for which there wudnt b any vote in alertDetails. 
When I execute above query i get *-0.2500* for those records.  Any ways to get 0 for such records there?

Comment: How are alertDetails related to the other two tables? There is no join condition so it is doing a cross product of that to the join of the other two tables.

Comment: Btw, it would also help if you used the appropriate table alias on each of the columns in the Select clause so we know what to what table each column belongs.

Comment: @Thomas ya i have done the editing as required. can not add join contion to query for alertDetails to alertMaster as it will nt give me desired results.

Comment: Yes you can. You just have to use it in a Left Join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a Left Join from AlertMaster to AlertDetails. However, your original query did not include any condition by which AlertDetails are related to the other two tables nor do we know from which table most of the columns are found because they do not include a table alias. Also, you should get out of the habit of using the comma-delimited syntax and should instead use the ISO Join syntax.

Lastly, you are trying to order on AlertDate but it is not included in the Group By clause. This is a "feature" of MySQL that IMO should be abandoned. The SQL specification requires that all columns in the Select clause exist in the Group By clause or a column be contained in an aggregate function. So, either group on alertDate or wrap it and the others in an aggregate function.

```
Select A.alertid
    , Min( A.alertTitle ) As alertTitle
    , Min( A.alertDetails ) As alertDetails
    , Min( A.alertDate ) As alertDate
    , Min( A.alertURL ) As alertUrl
    , Min( S.subTitle ) As subTitle
    , Coalesce( Avg( D.avgVote ), 0 ) As avgVote
From AlertMaster As A
    Join SubscriptionMaster As S
        On S.subid = A.subId
    Left Join AlertDetails As D
        On D.alertId = A.alertId
Where A.subId=1 
Group By A.alertId
Order By alertDate DESC 
Limit 0,10;
```

Comment: @OMG Ponies - Yep, yep. Was still in the process of determining exactly what was being requested and the schema. Have adjusted.

Comment: "*The SQL specification requires that all columns in the Select clause exist in the Group By clause or a column be contained in an aggregate function.*". Can you provide reference to that?

Comment: According to this article: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/debunking-group-by-myths.html , what you say it's true for the SQL 1992 standard but not for the 1999 and 2003 standards.

Comment: @ypercube - First, the readability argument alone is reason to adher to this rule as suggested by your author: *Of course, it is impossible to distinguish between a query that intentionally omits columns from the GROUP BY clause and one that accidentally forgot to include them.*. Second, my statement about the SQL specification is correct wrt to the 92 spec which IMO was built on far more solid ground than either the 99 or 03 specs. Third, I'm not entirely convinced he's interpreting the 99 or 03 spec correctly.